# Should data-test attribute be unique through modal and non-modal windows?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, modal-dialog, cypress

As far as I know, "data-test" (or "data-cy") attributes should be unique. Does it apply to modal windows, too? I mean if a non-modal plus an modal-window are open, should the "data-test" attributes of the elements be unique through both windows? Or is it enough to have unique "data-test"s through each window?